# Not able to create angular app in Red Hat 8

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, redhat

I am using Red Hat 8 in AWS EC2 instance. I have installed nodejs -

```
node -v
v10.16.3
npm -v
6.9.0
```

And I installed Angular CLI -

[image]

But when I am trying to create an app via angular CLI

```
ng create mytestapp
```

Its getting stuck on  **refresh-package-json:vary: sill refresh-package-json**

Not sure whats going wrong here.

[image]

Comment: ng create is not an existing command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refresh-package-json is a costly operation in terms of network bandwidth as it is downloading NPM packages to the instances. Smaller instances have a lower network bandwidth. Try increasing the size of your instance. For example: t2.micro = ~70 MBit/s whereas a t2.small = ~125 MBit/s (not exact numbers, just an example).